# Hotkey to move to next search result spanning multiple documents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I often do a search using Ctrl-Shift-F to see all the results appear in the Find Results window.  (in this case, look in would span the entire solution)

Is there a way to navigate each of the results using a hotkey?

I know that if you press F3 on the current document, it will go to the next entry but only in that document.  It will not jump to other documents. (nor will it highlight the search results that it has found)

It would be nice to emulate me clicking on a search result in the Find Result pane.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install Tool Productivity, it offer highlight the search

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

And in order to Navigate , you have arrow in order to navigate in the Find Result window

You can also go on this article it's very interessant

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/24/search-and-navigation-tips-tricks-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: It's a nice extension.  I'll have to check out all that it can do.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to provide a hotkey.

Comment: Looks like I found it, it's F8.  found here - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/24/search-and-navigation-tips-tricks-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: I'am happy to help you in your search Lareau